# i am receiving an error while returning `<IEnumerable<RiskValue>`.. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Risks>(jsonData);
             var finalResult = result.Value.Where(x => x.ID == 5).ToList();
             return finalResult;
```

I am working on an API that returns `<IEnumerable<RiskValue>` the deserializing does not cause any error this error is shown when I return the final result, any idea of what causing this?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON property name for 'MyProject.Models.RisksValue.ID' collides 
with another property.

System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON property name for 'test_1.Models.RisksValue.ID' collides with another property.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerPropertyNameConflict(Type type, JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo)
```

Comment: Hi @someone, could you please share your model design? The error message seems to indicate that your model contains two same name properties?

Comment: I have in the model `public int Id { get; set; }` and  `public string ID { get; set; }`

Comment: Leaving a comment since I cannot leave an answer:  
In my case, I had two properties with the same name, with the child class overriding the base class. I chose to rename the parent class' property and avoid serializing it, to solve this issue/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `false` in your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => { 
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; 
    
    //the importance here..
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
});
```

Comment: Just a note regarding OP's question: The model matters -- if 'Id' and 'ID' are conceptually different, then they should get different names. If access to modifying the model is not possible, I suggest a wrapper/transformation layer.